# jquery code to find/detect part of an image

Tags: jquery, image-processing, paperjs

I have a requirement to identify and locate an item within an image using jquery.

The image would contain a black circle, and I need to find that black circle and identify the coordinates of its center.

I know that paperjs.org offers fairly complex image manipulation features, but it won't meet my requirements without some extra code.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: jQuery library itself has nothing that will help you

Comment: I know that jQuery does not do this "out of the box".  That's why I pointed out that paperjs.org has a good image manipulation library, but I was more after an algorithm that might make use of this library (or any other suitable one), so that my requirements could be met.

Comment: What kind of image is it? I don't think paper.js will do you any good either because it is for manipulating vector images. If you have to do this in Javascript, you'll probably end up composing the image in a `canvas` and then using some fairly complex algorithm to find the circle in question.

Comment: paper.js does averaging of image colors at specified points.  See http://paperjs.org/tutorials/images/using-pixel-colors/ and http://paperjs.org/tutorials/images/color-averaging-image-areas/ for examples.  I think that gets me fairly close to what I need, but using that I need some sort of algorithm to take it further.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use [js-objectdetect](https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect) it also comes with a jQuery plugin.

> js-objectdetect is a javascript library for real-time object detection.
>
> This library is based on the work of Paul Viola and Rainer Lienhart and compatible to stump based cascade classifiers used by the OpenCV object detector.

Comment: That looks great.  I'll have to look further into it though, because at first glance, I can't get the examples to run due to cross-origin issues and WebRtc not being enabled.

Comment: It takes your webcam as an input, but I am sure it also works with static images. To get rid of the cross origin problem you have to run the example on a server.